# I want to use BossRC-5 loopstation in midi clock slave mode and be able to loop in to the beat but not the bar position or length basically loop in1/4

Tags: looping

I have a midi set up with drum machine and synth and 2 loop pedals TC ditto x 4 and Boss RC-5. All clocked from a midironone.
The TC ditto x 4 clocks to the beat so you can easily record loop of any no. of beats, 3/4 5/4 whatever. Starting at the nearest beat to pedal press ending at nearest beat to next press. Perfect

The Boss RC-5 seems to only record to a set measure length set in the menu and what’s more can only start from the beginning of the bar. A setting where you could select 1/4 would solve this. Unfortunately there is no such setting.

Anyone know how to do this? Please help

Comment: If they haven't fixed the problem in the RC-3 where you could only set the time signature to 3/4 or 4/4, the tempo was auto-detected and you could only change the tempo by tapping it in, then you are stuck. Otherwise, if you can set the time signature to 2 and set the tempo by knob twirling, then set the tempo on the RC-5 to double your desired tempo and then you have 2/8, which is 1/4.

Comment: Thanks for replying unfortunately when synced Will drum machine and other pedal tempo is from midi clock, so can’t do double tempo thing without changing the Drums etc,:(